# Specifying Cipher Suit of Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

Hello I recently set up SSL on my server, and the clients that connect to it need to know what cipher suit to use.  I use Let's Encrypt certbot on an Ubuntu 20 server and NGINX webserver.

I was following this tutorial from start to finish: [MQTT Broker Setup](https://obrienlabs.net/how-to-setup-your-own-mqtt-broker/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20setup%20your%20own%20MQTT%20Broker.%201,Setup%20LetsEncrypt%20SSL%20certificate%20%28optional%29%20%20More%20items) but it doesn't really get into that level of detail.  However, my client devices lists:[image: cipher suit table]

Is there a default cipher suit that I can expect or a way to look through the lets encrypt files on the server to see what it is using?  In general who determines the cipher suit to be used?

Comment: For TLS1.2 (and below, which are no longer recommended) the type of key in the certificate constrains the ciphersuite(s) used. certbot defaults to RSA but you can select or configure ECDSA. Depending on that, and given OpenSSL 1.1.1 as on Ubuntu 20.04, `openssl ciphers -stdname aRSA:kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!eNULL` or `openssl ciphers -stdname ECDSA:!eNULL` shows the available suites (ignoring the lines for 1.3 if your client doesn't support it). If you want security, suites beginning TLS_ECDHE_{RSA,ECDSA}_WITH_AES are usually best, but that's mostly offtopic. ...

Comment: ... Also or instead, there are lots of tools and services that probe a running server to see what it offers. `nmap` is packaged for Ubuntu, and there are others like `sslscan`. If the server is publicly accessible, which is normally the case if you use LE, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ is a thorough test that among other things lists the ciphersuites offered, and again there are others.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 if I understand correctly are you saying that the server will support various cipher suites but I can specify in the client to use for example 0X0035 and the server will align with this?  Or has the server already determined what cipher suit it will use?

Comment: SSL/TLS client offers one or more suite(s), and server selects from that list any one it supports, unless there are none; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Description and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/ . If server has RSA cert then 0x0035 will work, although 0xC027 0xC028 or 0xC02F is better.